# Google map is not working in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

i am using the following code using  [goole-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) npm i follow all the steps properlly but map is not load in my browser

here is my code :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class GooogleMap extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.95,
      lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
  };

  render() {
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key:"my API_key"}}

          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={'59.955413'}
            lng={'30.337844'}
            text={'Kreyser Avrora'}
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GooogleMap;
```

and i am gettin this thing on my browser :-

[image]

Comment: No idea why this happens, instead I have a question for you :) did you consider using expo with its great maps support?

Comment: sorry to say but expo is for react native apps not for react js

Comment: Oops right. I should have read your question slower. Sorry :)

Comment: Any console errors?  Sure your API key is valid?

Comment: Works for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xvqzfy. Place your api key

Comment: yes i am using my api key in other project and it works great for them

Comment: @kboul no it does not work for me. is there any other way to integrate google map in reactjs

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-map-key-error

Comment: did your key exceed the daily limit?

Comment: no i dont think so because i am only one who is using that key

Comment: can your share codesandbox here ? Anyways have you tried react-google-maps it's community is huge.